# Creating New Column in SQL with Regex

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the result set which contains a list of years. But some of the entries have years menioned as VII2016 or II2014. How can write a query for creating a new column with original years i.e 2000,2002 and with modified 2014 and 2016.

Here is my code:

```
WITH female_year_count as
(SELECT m.year as f FROM Movie m
JOIN M_Cast c ON m.MID=c.MID
JOIN Person p ON trim(c.PID)=p.PID
WHERE trim(p.Gender) = 'Female'
)
SELECT * FROM female_year_count
```

I am using SQLite3 library in Python. Please let me know how to write that query.

Comment: Are you saying that the column "year" contains values like "2000", and "2002", but also "VII2016" and "II2014" ? And if that is what you are saying, how does one set of values relate to another? I don't get how you want to convert 2000,2002 to 2014,2016.

Comment: I have the year column that contains years along with some alphabets like VI2016 and III2014. I want all my values to represented in numbers like VI 2016 should be converted to 2016 and III2014 should be converted to 2014. I am using SQLite3 library on Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the year is always the four last chars of the field value, you can use `substr`. Here's a proof of concept:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:').cursor()
>>> c.execute("CREATE TEMP TABLE t(x)").execute(
... "INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VI2016'), ('III2014'), ('2018'), (NULL)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at ...>
```

Original data is:

```
>>> c.execute("SELECT x FROM t").fetchall()
[('VI2016',), ('III2014',), ('2018',), (None,)]
```

Take the 4 rightmost chars:

```
>>> c.execute("SELECT substr(x, length(x)-3, 4) FROM t").fetchall()
[('2016',), ('2014',), ('2018',), (None,)]
```

You may want to cast the year to an int:

```
>>> c.execute("SELECT CAST(substr(x, length(x)-3, 4) AS int) FROM t").fetchall()
[(2016,), (2014,), (2018,), (None,)]
```